# Solving osgi classloading issues with jax-rs clients

Tags: java, osgi

Imagine you have a module A which provides a static method that is used by module B. This method uses a jax-rs client to retrieve information from a webservice. The information is returned as a string. Module B is already a osgi bundle. Now module A also needs to be transformed to an osgi bundle but it is not allowed to change any code of it. So you can only add the required metadata to the manifest file. I did that and embedded all dependencies (including a jax-rs client) into a single jar file. Now, if module B calls the static method of module A I get a `ClassNotFoundException` since the classloader of module B is used to find the jax-rs client. I did some debugging and if I execute the line `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader())` in module A everything works, because now the classloader of module A is used and the client is found on the classpath of that module. Since I cannot change any code of module A this solution does not work for me. Does anyone has another hint for me how I can deal with these classloading issues?

Answer (score 1):

Create **bundle C** with dependencies that satisfy both **bundle A and B**.

The modularity of OSGi is a strength, not a weakness. If there is some third party code that should be shared, better to put it in his own bundle.

Now, you just have to make sure the manifest of bundle A and B import the same stuff.

Comment: I am not quite sure why this is going to help me. So you say instead of calling A from B, I call C from B. Then still the classloader of B is used and dependencies on the classpath of C are not found. The only thing I could image is adding the code `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader())` to module C. Then it should work. Or is there another way?

Comment: Bundle B still calls the method in A. But whatever class they need, is inside Bundle C.

Comment: I still think this won't help me. The problem is that there is a property file in the `META-INF/services`folder of one dependency. This file is accessed via reflection and so the classloader of module A has to be used to find that file since that module provides the jax-rs client. With your solution still the wrong classloader would be used.

Comment: If you really have to use **ServiceLoaders**,  more code are necessary https://blog.osgi.org/2013/02/javautilserviceloader-in-osgi.html. But the overall solution still apply.